# ObservableArray.push() triggers click event

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm making a searchable list of objects (students). When I append objects to list, I also want to add click event handler, which will pass me the objects Id.

I've made an observable array:

```
<script>
self.studentList = ko.observableArray();

// (...) if search conditions are met, add student to array
self.studentList.push(singleStudent);

</script>
```

And it's html:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: studentList">
<tr>
    <td><span data-bind='text: $data.Name, click: ClickEvent($data.Id)'></span></td>
</tr>
```

And function which should be triggered on click:

```
<script>
    function ClickEvent(pId)
    {
        console.log(pId);
    }
</script>
```

The clicking itself works fine. The problem is, that the `self.studentList.push(singleStudent)` line ALSO triggers the event.

How can I add event that would be triggered ONLY if element is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not correctly wired your `click` handler, because you haven't passed in a reference to your function but the actual executed result.

In its current form `ClickEvent` is executed every time when the binding is parsed, e.g. when you add a new item to your array.

To fix it you need to wrap it to an anonymous function

```
<td>
  <span data-bind='text: $data.Name, click: function() { ClickEvent($data.Id) }'></span>
</td>
```

Or you can use the [`bind` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
<td>
  <span data-bind='text: $data.Name, click: ClickEvent.bind($data, $data.Id)'></span>
</td>
```

See also in the documentation: [Accessing the event object, or passing more parameters](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-2-accessing-the-event-object-or-passing-more-parameters)